# Swiper Slider implementation in React JS + Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, material-ui

I have the following app  architecture:

1 parent component and  4 child components, each is activated based on  a state of the parent component

```
<Tabs>
      <Tab
        icon={<EuroLogo />}
        onActive={()=>this.setState({page:1})}
        label="price"
        style={stylesTab}
      />
      <Tab
        icon={<LocationLogo />}
        onActive={()=>this.setState({page:2})}
        label="distance"
        style={stylesTab}
      />
      <Tab
        icon={<FuleLogo />}
        onActive={()=>this.setState({page:3})}
        label="fule"
        style={stylesTab}
      />
      <Tab
        icon={<DataLogo />}
        onActive={()=>this.setState({page:4})}
        label="data"
        style={stylesTab}
      />
</Tabs>
```

the `render()` is as follows:

```
<div>
      {
      (() => {  switch(this.state.page){
          case 1: {
             return <Price/>
           } break;
          case 2: {
             return <Distance/>
           } break;
          case 3: {
            return <Fuel/>
          } break;
          case 4: {
            return <Options/>
          } break;
        }

      }
    )()}
</div>
```

The page change is based on the value of the parent state.page

My question is, how can I  implement react slider swiper. I  searched on the net  for info  but did not found any  documentation or videos ..  for ReactJS WEB

P.S. Sorry for the NOT "exact /detailed problem" question, but will realy appreciate if someone helps me, or links me some documentation or video :)

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slider-swiper) would probably be a good place to start. The examples seem to be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Hey while we are on the subject,  can you explain how {...stuff} works, I mean  the {...} triple dots

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator